# Memory leak UIStatusBarHideAnimationParameters

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Instruments in XCode and using 'Leaks'. I am getting a leaked object after dismissing the `UIImagePickerController`.

In the details panel, I see the leaked object as `UIStatusBarHideAnimationParameters`.

I am not able to understand where this is coming from. Following is my code -

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // Handles when the image has been picked
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;
    BOOL dismissed = NO;

    [_activityIndicator show];

    if (CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 0.1);
        imageToSave = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        // Display the image in the image view
        [self displayImageInImageView:imageToSave];

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [_activityIndicator show];
            [self uploadPhotoToS3SyncWithImage:imageToSave];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5];
            [_nextButton setEnabled:YES];
            [_uploadPhotoButton setTitle:@"Upload Another" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:RIDEPhotoUploadToSetLocationSegue sender:self];
        }];

        dismissed = YES;
    }

    if (!dismissed) {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

When I click on the stack trace in the extended details panel, the line `dismissed = YES` is highlighted by XCode. But AFAIK `BOOL` variables do not have to deallocated. Neither does `picker` with ARC.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you need to clear the delegate for your UIImagePickerController? Delegates can prevent objects from being properly deallocated.

Comment: Yes, seems like that was the case. I set the delegate of the picker to nil and I am no longer seeing this particular memory leak. Thanks.